# Can we join the data of different type in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a data of different types which share the common attribute between them. The example data is as below. I need to run a query which could return me the count of REFs which are closed on a particular date. As for as I have searched on google elastic search does not support joins, so I was looking for some alternative ways to achieve this. Could you please help on this?

```
  "REF": "1234", "date" : "2017-09-13T21:59:59.999999", "_type":"action"
  "REF": "1234", "date" : "2017-09-14T15:59:59.999999", "_type":"action"
  "REF": "12", "date" : "2017-09-13T20:59:59.999999", "_type":"action"
  "REF": "12", "date" : "2017-09-14T21:59:59.999999", "_type":"action"

  "REF": "1234", "status" : "open", "_type":"data"
  "REF": "1234", "status" : "closed", "_type":"data"
  "REF": "12", "status" : "open", "_type":"data"
  "REF": "12", "status" : "closed", "_type":"data"
  "REF": "123", "status" : "open", "_type":"data"
  "REF": "1", "status" : "open", "_type":"data"
```

Note: The date in _type actions suggests the date of row entered in the _type data for either open or closed status.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put `date` in same type?

Comment: No, this is how I get data in elastic search from two different sources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this data in getting into ES so I'm not 100% on what's the best approach.  Here's a few ideas -

- Set up a [parent-child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html) in your mappings
- Route your data through [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to do an ETL
- Do 2 queries. In SQL terms you can think of the 1st one as what would be in the IN() clause, then the 2nd as the SELECT by.  Using reverse indexes isn't un-common in no-sql land.